# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, fatal-error

```
I have uninstalled java 8 and only have java 7 on my machine but I get the following error when I try to compile using maven 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project MyApp: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

I can not remove the java*.exe files from Windows/system32 or 64 because I am not an admin, neither do I have an option to get an access their. Any other way to solve this issue?

Also, when I do $ java -version or $ javac - version, I do not get any error and the java7 version is displayed.

Comment: Your pom is setup to target Java 1.8; which you have now removed.

Comment: What development environment are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , I have already made the pom file change : <properties>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
 </properties>

Comment: @lucasvw, I am using Eclipse. However I am trying to build my maven project through command prompt. I am using java7.